# One word for limited or piecemeal benefit

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm writing a paper on data strategy for large corporates. In this paper I define 4 levels of maturity on the path to a Google-like nirvana state where corporate, client, user, and other data is managed strategically to deliver true business benefit.

My four levels are:

- Data Debt Despondency (or Doldrums)
- MIS Mediocrity
- BI **limited benefit**
- Data Exemplar/Luminary/Doyen (not sure about this name yet.)

For completeness, MIS = *Management Information Services* and BI = *Business Intelligence* - both jargon for types of software solution designed to extract business benefit from data.

I like the alliterative nature of the first two names, and so I'd like to follow that example for the 3rd and 4th levels too, if I can.

My question is, can someone suggest 1 word that means "limited benefit"? Bonus points if it starts with a B and double bonus points if you can also suggest a nice alliterative name for the 4th, nirvana level.

Answer (score 1):

*Benefit* itself fits the scheme well. You don't need to qualify it or use a more specific word if it's clear from context (the second & fourth tiers) that it's better than mediocrity but less than perfection.

For the fourth tier, if you want an actual nirvana metaphor, consider using *Dharma* – but check first with somebody more knowledgeable about Buddhism to help judge whether it's accurate and inoffensive.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting it to something beginning with B is making it tougher, although I can see that you want to complete the set!  BI ***Bestowal*** - that's as close as I could think immediately with bestowal meaning "a gift presented..."

You could also use BI ***Belief*** as this allows you to interpret it as you will - some believe BI is amazing, but belief is not fact...

Comment: Belief has merit. I also considered "betterment" but it doesn't quite cut the mustard. I'm happy to forgo the alliteration if the word is particularly cool.

Answer (score 0):

Consider  “blocked benefit” or “borderline benefits”, and  “data deity”.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @bradd-szonye *Benefit* itself is sufficient for your purpose.

Unfortunately he is wrong on the *Dharma* part. Dharma is more akin to what's called destiny or divine duty (the concepts are not distinguishable in the East).

Suggestion: *Delight* (nothing better than simplicity...although there's an off chance that someone may take it for an ice-cream flavor)